# PHP Eclipse syntax color change

Tags: php, eclipse

How can I change the PHP variables color in Eclipse?  It is very light blue/gray by default.  I go to preferences and click on all the editors but doesn't seem it is there.

By the way, I install the Eclipse 3.5.1 with PHPEclipse 1.2.x plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am using Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers version 1.2.x and my path is as follows,

```
Preferences > PHP > Editor > Syntax Coloring > Variable
```

Try to download the [**PHP Development Tools (PDT)**](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) instead of PHPEclipse

Comment: Well.. i only have 
Preferences > PhpEclipse > PHP
or 
Preferences > PhpEclipse > PHP Extneral Tools


then there is no syntax coloring.


I find there is for "java".  It may do too but I don't want to mess up the syntax color for java file. :)

Comment: I would suggest downloading *Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers* updated my answer to include the link.

Comment: the problem is.... Eclipse IDE for PHP is win32.  And I really can't find the 64 bit one. So, I stuck with installing the 'regular' 64bit Eclipse (java) and then do the PHPEclipse plugin.

Comment: I hope the 64-bit Windows version comes out soon for your sake. If I find anything helpful, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks. :) I spent hours of install Eclipse for PHP.. and hours of trying to figuring out how to change the syntax color. I think I just stick with the default color for now. :)

Comment: downvoting because it doesn't answer the question, but suggest install other IDE

Answer (score 3):

I have eclipse Helios running with 'PHPEclipse' plugin. I was able to resolve similar issue by making sure PHP files open with 'PHP Editor'.

1. Right-click on the file, select 'open with' -> 'Other'.
2. Choose 'PHP Editor'.

You can set 'syntax coloring preferences' at Window -> Preferences -> PHPEclipse -> PHP -> Tab syntax